# Настройка шрифта консольной программы CodeBlocks

Tags: ubuntu, codeblocks

Установил Ubuntu, поставил CodeBlocks. Все хорошо, одно плохо: при запуске  программы(консольной) нельзя поменять шрифт консоли(он довольно маленький, побольше хочу поставить). При нажатии правой кнопкой на консоль не реагирует. При нажатии правой кнопкой на заголовок окна консоли реагирует, но никаких настроек там нет. И что странно у консоли цвета отичаются от цветов терминала(изменение шрифта в терминале не помогло). Как можно настроить шрифт?
Ubuntu 14, CodeBlocks 13.12

Answer (score 1):

Уже нашел ответ. Дело в том что CodeBlocks использует для консоли не терминал а xterm. Потому надо просто пойти в настройки Settings -> Environment и поменять Terminal to launch console programs на родной терминал.